# Give program time to shutdown threads but with System.exit backup plan?

Tags: java, multithreading

Sometimes the system process of a java application doesn't fully shutdown. This is mainly because one or more threads didn't die.

One can call:

```
System.exit(0);
```

But this kills all threads.

I want all my threads to shutdown correctly so i don't plan on using System.exit. But sometimes due to circumstances one or more threads don't die correctly. This causes the application to not fully shutdown and linger in the background sometimes even locking up resources.

My first thought was writing an ExitWatcher which starts when program stops and calls system.exit after 10 seconds if the program is still alive. I quickly found out that the ExitWatcher now prevents the program from shutting down ;-)

How do you give a java program time to shutdown correctly (ie close all threads correctly) but at the same time have a backup plan that calls System.exit if shutdown takes too long?

Comment: As Kayaman mentions I think you could make your ExitWatcher thread a daemon, but also the whole idea is kind of fraught.  What if some important data takes more than 10 seconds to save (say over a slow network connection)?  Seems like you're just shooting yourself in the foot.  Better to concentrate on the individual threads and make certain that they all will exit when they are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use daemon threads when you don't want a thread to prevent a program from exiting (so using `setDaemon(true)` on your `ExitWatcher` thread would solve your immediate problem). However I doubt you really need or want an ExitWatcher, as situations like that are usually relatively easily prevented with proper design.

Proper shutdown procedures include interrupting threads that are active (and designing them so they behave nicely when interrupted), using daemon threads where necessary, shutting down connections properly etc. Using a mechanism like your ExitWatcher is more of a hackish approach, as it indicates your program doesn't always behave nicely at shutdown.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman , setDaemon trick works nicely! It indeed is a good thing to keep track of threads and close them correctly, one of the reason i don't use System.exit. But under certain circumstances this causes problems leading to users needing to restart computers to get everything working again. Having something like ExitWatcher is not something nice, but sometimes better than the alternatives.

Comment: The best alternative to ExitWatcher is to fix the bugs in your program. The only places where that sort of mechanism is reasonable is when you're running someone else's code. This is why app servers will fill the logs with all sorts of warnings and curses if your webapp doesn't behave nicely. It's trying to say "fix your program, I can't do anything to it".